# How to use condition within input tag using php?

Tags: php, mysql

If specific condition is true make input field readonly.

```
$todayDate = date('Y-m-d');
```

Here is the condition

```
$row["date"] == $todayDate (make input readonly  true otherwise false)
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $output .= '
        <tbody><tr>
            <td>'.$row["date"].'</td>
            <td><input type="text" value = "'.$row["actual_closing_balance"].'"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>';
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are going to do with it.. But you know somebody can remove the `readonly` so the form send it again?.. Most simple way is just to show the data in the table cell.

Comment: in my case,user need to edit the input field based on certain condition

Comment: Note, you should not include `<tbody>` and `</tbody>` in your loop since they will appear around each new line.  These tags should only be present once per table.  Only the `<tr><td></td></tr>` tags should be in the loop.

Comment: "in my case,user need to edit the input field based on certain condition " Then show the input without readonly when it matches that condition and if it does not match the condition show it in the table cell. Makes sure you also check the condition in the php file where you send the post

Comment: @RaymondNijland can u give a code for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
[ ... OTHER HTML ...]

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Date</th><th>Actual closing balance</th></tr>
    </thead>
<?php
    $todayDate = date('Y-m-d');

    $output = "<tbody>\n";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $readonly = '';
        if ($row['date'] == "$todayDate")
        {
            $readonly = 'readonly="readonly"';
        }
        $output .= "    <tr><td>$row[date]</td><td><input type=\"text\" $readonly value=\"$row[actual_closing_balance].\"></td></tr>\n";
    }
    $output .= "</tbody>\n";
    print $output;
 ?>
 </table>

 [...OTHER HTML...]
```

This way you have a properly formatted table (`<tbody>` tags appear only once).  And you verify each row for the readonly attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$readonly = '';
if($row['date'] == $todayDate){
    $readonly = 'readonly';
}


'<input type="text" value = "'.$row["actual_closing_balance"].' '.$readonly.' />';
```

Comment: its not working i put like this <td><input type="text"  value = "'.$row["actual_closing_balance"].'"                                                          
 '.$readonly.'   ></td>

Comment: Not sure which html doctype you are using @Diamond but xhtml requires `readonly="readonly"`

Comment: html5 am using now

Comment: `readonly="true"` and also `readonly="false"` is not valid html.. @Diamond make sure to valid the html https://validator.w3.org/ .. Browsers might show the html wrong when the html is not valid.

Comment: You can copy the generated html source an use validate by input @Diamond